# Javascript - (10<3<10) return true

Tags: javascript

Why does `(10<3<10)` return true in Javascript? `3<10` but `10<3` is false. So it should return `false`

Comment: Actually, the reason it should return false is because 10 cannot possibly `<3` being less than 10 because 10 *is not less than* 10.

Comment: Most languages don't support the double comparison like that.

Comment: You can't really use two operators, so operator presedence kicks in, and it's read `( (10<3) < 10 )` which equals `( false < 10 )` which is true

Comment: @BoltClock, `4<3<10` also true)

Comment: This has been asked and answered here on SO at least once before, but I don't have the link handy. *Edit*: Oh, hey, it was right there in the "related" list. Which means it was on the "Your question may already have an answer" list shown to you before you posted the question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am a newbie))) (registered yesterday)!

Comment: because zero is less than 3...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`10<3<10` is  equivalent to `(10<3)<10`. `10<3` is `false`, `false<10` is true.

Comment: Is `false` converted to `0` for the comparison?

Comment: Wow! I thought it is more mysterious)))

Comment: otherwise, 10 converted to true...

Comment: @TimS.: Yes. The relational operators can act on strings or numbers, and prefer numbers. So if both sides support being converted to numbers (and bools do), it'll go with that.

Comment: yup! Which is very strange for me, and PHP acts like that too. I like Ruby (which this kind of nonsense doesn't happen)!

Comment: there is not strong types)

Answer (score 2):

because

```
Number(false)
```

is `0` and `10<3` is `false`.